# typedef of a multidimensional array?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, typedef

```
typedef int array [x][];
```

What does that means. What will happen if we have such a typedef. It was my interview question.

Answer (score 8):

Let's assume you have somewhere:

```
#define x 3
```

As others point out, `typedef int array [3][];` will not compile. You can only omit the most significant (ie first) element of an array length.

But you *can* say:

```
typedef int array [][3];
```

This means that `array` is an int array (of as-yet unspecified length) of length 3 arrays.

To use it, you need to specify the length. You can do this by using an initialiser like so:

```
array A = {{1,2,3,},{4,5,6}};   // A now has the dimensions [2][3]
```

But you CAN'T say:

```
array A;
```

In this case, `A`'s first dimension isn't specified, so the compiler doesn't know how much space to allocate for it.

Note that it's also fine to use this `array` type in a function definition - as arrays in function definitions are always converted to pointers to their first element by the compiler:

```
// these are all the same
void foo(array A);
void foo(int A[][3]);
void foo(int (*A)[3]); // this is the one the compiler will see
```

Note that in this case:

```
void foo(int A[10][3]);
```

The compiler still sees

```
void foo(int (*A)[3]);
```

So, the `10` part of `A[10][3]` is ignored.

In summary:

```
typedef int array [3][]; // incomplete type, won't compile
typedef int array [][3]; // int array (of as-yet unspecified length) 
                         // of length 3 arrays
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll get a compilation error. For multidimensional arrays, at most the first dimension may be omitted. So for example, `int array[][x]` would be valid instead.

Comment: For more details on the typedef parsing:
http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter8/typedef.html

Answer (score 1):

You'll get a diagnostic.

`int [x][]` is an incomplete array type that cannot be completed.